# Using a .config function in another file with Typescript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have this code in a file called config.ts

```
app.config(['abc', function (abc) {
    // some code here
}])
```

Can someone tell me how I can move the function to another file and use Typescript for this? In particular I want to ensure that I don't have a problem when the code is mimified. Here is what I was thinking but I am not sure this is correct:

File myFunc.ts

```
 myFunc => (['abc', function (abc) {
    // some code here
}])
```

File config.ts

```
 app.config(myFunc)
```

Hopefully someone can help me to head in the right direction. In particular what I am not sure about is how to inject the parameters into the function with typescript. If the function was a class then I know how to do it but .config does not accept a class as its argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use external modules and then bundle with a loader.

File `myFunc.ts`

```
export const myFunc = () => (['abc', function (abc) {
    // some code here
}])
```

File `config.ts`

```
import {myFunc} from "./myFunc";
app.config(myFunc)
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. I would like to use external modules but at this time that would mean quite a few changes to my code. If you don't mind can you also give me the answer on how to do this without using external modules and just with putting the function in a file.  Is it just that the file would contain myFunc = () => (['abc', function (abc) {
    // some code here
}])  Thanks

Comment: You would need to use `--out` and out is bad ! https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md